# _AMQ_GROUP_ID present in message but JMSXGroupID null in @JmsListener

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

From this documentation:

> Messages in a message group share the same group id, i.e. they have same group identifier property (JMSXGroupID for JMS, _AMQ_GROUP_ID for Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Core API).

I can see why the property originally set via `JMSXGroupID` becomes `_AMQ_GROUP_ID` when I browse the messages in the broker with a value of product=paper.  However, In my `@JmsListener` annotated method I can see the `_AMQ_GROUP_ID` property is missing and the `JMSXGroupID` is coming through as null in the Message's `headers` hashmap.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${artemis.destination}", subscription = "${artemis.subscriptionName}",
            containerFactory = "containerFactory", concurrency = "15-15")
public void consumeMessage(Message<StatefulSpineEvent<?>> eventMessage)
```

So

1. My Producer application sends the message to the queue after setting the string property `JMSXGroupID` to 'product=paper'
2. I can see `_AMQ_GROUP_ID` has a value of 'product=paper' when I browse that message's headers in the Artemis UI
3. When I debug my listener application and look at the map of headers, `_AMQ_GROUP_ID` is absent and `JMSXGroupID` has a value of null instead of 'product=paper'.

Is the character '=' invalid or is there something else that can cause this?  I'm running out of things to try.

Edit, with new code:

HeaderMapper:

```
@Component
public class GroupIdMessageMapper extends SimpleJmsHeaderMapper {

    @Override
    public MessageHeaders toHeaders(Message jmsMessage) {

        MessageHeaders messageHeaders = super.toHeaders(jmsMessage);

        Map<String, Object> messageHeadersMap = new HashMap<>(messageHeaders);

        try {
            messageHeadersMap.put("JMSXGroupID", jmsMessage.getStringProperty("_AMQ_GROUP_ID"));
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // can see while debugging that this returns the correct headers
        return new MessageHeaders(messageHeadersMap);
    }
}
```

Listener:

```
@Component
public class CustomSpringJmsListener {

    protected final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @JmsListener(destination = "local-queue", subscription = "groupid-example",
            containerFactory = "myContainerFactory", concurrency = "15-15")
    public void receive(Message message) throws JMSException {
        LOG.info("Received message: " + message);
    }
}
```

Application code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class GroupidApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(GroupidApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Autowired MessageConverter messageConverter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOG.info("STARTING THE APPLICATION");
        SpringApplication.run(GroupidApplication.class, args);

        LOG.info("APPLICATION FINISHED");
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        LOG.info("EXECUTING : command line runner");

        jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);

        createAndSendObjectMessage("Message1");
        createAndSendTextMessage("Message2");
        createAndSendTextMessage("Message3");
        createAndSendTextMessage("Message4");
        createAndSendTextMessage("Message5");
        createAndSendTextMessage("Message6");
    }

    private void createAndSendTextMessage(String messageBody) {
        jmsTemplate.send("local-queue", session -> {
            Message message = session.createTextMessage(messageBody);

            message.setStringProperty("JMSXGroupID", "product=paper");

            return message;
        });
    }

    // BEANS

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        // This provides all boot's default to this factory, including the message converter
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        // You could still override some of Boot's default if necessary.
        factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
        factory.setSubscriptionShared(true);
        factory.setMessageConverter(messagingMessageConverter());

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessagingMessageConverter messagingMessageConverter() {
        return new MessagingMessageConverter(messageConverter, new GroupIdMessageMapper());
    }
}
```

Stack trace of where SimpleJmsHeaderMapper is being called:

> toHeaders:130, SimpleJmsHeaderMapper (org.springframework.jms.support)
>   toHeaders:57, SimpleJmsHeaderMapper (org.springframework.jms.support)
>   extractHeaders:148, MessagingMessageConverter
>   (org.springframework.jms.support.converter) access$100:466,
>   AbstractAdaptableMessageListener$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter
>   (org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter) getHeaders:552,
>   AbstractAdaptableMessageListener$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter$LazyResolutionMessage
>   (org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter) resolveArgumentInternal:68,
>   HeaderMethodArgumentResolver
>   (org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support)
>   resolveArgument:100, AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver
>   (org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support)
>   resolveArgument:117, HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite
>   (org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation)
>   getMethodArgumentValues:148, InvocableHandlerMethod
>   (org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation) invoke:116,
>   InvocableHandlerMethod
>   (org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation) invokeHandler:114,
>   MessagingMessageListenerAdapter
>   (org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter) onMessage:77,
>   MessagingMessageListenerAdapter
>   (org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter) doInvokeListener:736,
>   AbstractMessageListenerContainer (org.springframework.jms.listener)
>   invokeListener:696, AbstractMessageListenerContainer
>   (org.springframework.jms.listener) doExecuteListener:674,
>   AbstractMessageListenerContainer (org.springframework.jms.listener)
>   doReceiveAndExecute:318, AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer
>   (org.springframework.jms.listener) receiveAndExecute:257,
>   AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer
>   (org.springframework.jms.listener) invokeListener:1190,
>   DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker
>   (org.springframework.jms.listener) executeOngoingLoop:1180,
>   DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker
>   (org.springframework.jms.listener) run:1077,
>   DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker
>   (org.springframework.jms.listener) run:748, Thread (java.lang)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try subclassing the `SimpleJmsHeaderMapper` and override `toHeaders()`. Call `super.toHeaders()`, create a new `Map<>` from the result; `put()` any additional headers you want into the map and return a new `MessageHeaders` from the map.

Pass the custom mapper into a new `MessagingMessageConverter` and pass that into the container factory.

If you are using Spring Boot, simply add the converter as a `@Bean` and boot will auto wire it into the factory.

**EDIT**

After all this; I just wrote an app and it works just fine for me without any customization at all...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So58399905Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So58399905Application.class, args);
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "foo")
    public void listen(String in, MessageHeaders headers) {
        System.out.println(in + headers);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(JmsTemplate template) {
        return args -> template.convertAndSend("foo", "bar", msg -> {
            msg.setStringProperty("JMSXGroupID", "product=x");
            return msg;
        });
    }

}
```

and

```
bar{jms_redelivered=false, JMSXGroupID=product=x, jms_deliveryMode=2, JMSXDeliveryCount=1,  ...
```

**EDIT2**

It's a bug in the artemis client - with 2.6.4 (Boot 2.1.9) only `getStringProperty()` returns the value of the `_AMQ_GROUP_ID` property when getting `JMSXGroupID`.

The mapper uses `getObjectProperty()` which returned null. With the 2.10.1 client; the message properly returns the value of the `_AMQ_GROUP_ID` property from `getObjectProperty()`.

Comment: Sorry are you suggesting that I statically put the headers into the map myself on the listener side?  I need them to come from the message's headers in the queue.  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: No; I am assuming that Artemis is sending it (this is just a guess), just that the default Spring header mapper knows nothing about it so it's not mapped into the message that is used to call the `JmsListener`.

Comment: Oh, sorry; I just looked at the Message javadocs: `{@code JMSXGroupID} and {@code JMSXGroupSeq} are standard 
  properties that clients 
  should use if they want to group messages.` I was assuming it was a first class header rather than a simple property. The default mapper maps all properties so if it's `null` then it means the Artemis client is not providing it in the Jms `Message`.

Comment: OK.  You're right.  That mapper class just isn't honoring that conversion from _AMQ_GROUP_ID to JMSXGroupId.  I observed that group id wasn't working (same group id was processed by two different jms listener containers) so I thought it wasn't in the jms message at all but apparently it is.  Anyway That's a separate question I'll have to ask in another stackoverflow question.

Comment: Well, to be clear, it's not Spring's responsibility to map a custom header name to a standard one. It certainly doesn't do the reverse on the outbound side; the mapper is agnostic about the JMS provider. Artemis must be doing that outbound; they should be consistent and map it symmetrically on the inbound side.

Comment: That actually didn't do it.  It does enter my new `CustomHeaderMapper` but that get's overridden later during processing of the message for some reason by a call to the `SimpleJmsHeaderMapper` itself

Comment: You need to inject your custom mapper into the container factory. Edit the question to show your current code/configuration.

Comment: I don't see how a SJHM can be called because you have replaced the default with your own. Maybe set a breakpoint in the SJHM to see where it is being called from?

Comment: Added a stack trace.

Comment: Oh sorry,  I also have a `@Header` annotated parameter in my `consumeMessage` method.  I think that's where the call is coming from.  Was trying to give you the most basic version.

Comment: In any case; I just tested it and it works fine for me without any custom mapper. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Probably because you aren't using Artemis.  The transition never happens between "_AMQ_GROUP_ID" and JMSXGroupID

Comment: Yes I am (embedded though: `org.apache.activemq:artemis-jms-server`).

Comment: Can you see `_AMQ_GROUP_ID` in the jmsMessage before the headers are mapped?  As far as I can tell is should be impossible for SJHM to map _AMQ_GROUP_ID

Comment: The embedded broker doesn't have a console so I just tested with a stand-alone broker and it **still** works; I see it as `_AMQ_GROUP_ID` on the console but when I set a breakpoint in the mapper, I see `jmsPropertyNames` = `[JMSXGroupID, JMSXDeliveryCount]` - so the mapping just works since all properties are mapped. What versions are you using (I am testing using Boot 2.2.0, Spring-jms 5.2.0 artemis client 2.10.1).

Comment: You can see the simple mapper mapping the value from _AMQ_GROUP_ID to JMSXGroupID?  For me it is setting JMSXGroupID but always to null.

I'm using spring-boot-starter-artemis with spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.1.9 and my local version of artemis is 2.7.0

I'll try with a new version of artemis.  Mine isn't too old but I know they push out bug fixes like crazy.

Comment: No; the simple mapper does nothing special; by the time the JMS `Message` gets to the mapper (received from the Artemis client), there is no sign of the `_AMQ_GROUP_ID` - it's already `JMSXGroupID` in the message properties with the correct value... I just downgraded to Boot 2.1.9, which pulls in the 2.6.4 artemis client and it **still** all works fine for me; my local Artemis broker is 2.10.1.

Comment: I just did a wireshark trace and I see `_AMQ_GROUP_ID` on the wire - so the conversion must be done in the artemis client. Maybe you have an old one somehow?

Comment: I was mistaken; I get `null` with Boot 2.1.9 too. It's a **bug in the artemis client** - with 2.6.4 only `getStringProperty()` returns the value of the `_AMQ_GROUP_ID` property. The mapper uses `getObjectProperty()` which returned null. With the 2.10.1 client; the message properly returns the value of the `_AMQ_GROUP_ID` property from `getObjectProperty()`.