# Message grouping with Artemis and Spring JMS not working when using transacted sessions

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

Message grouping doesn't appear to be working

1. My Producer application sends the message to the queue via JMS [`MessageProducer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageProducer.html) after setting the string property `JMSXGroupID` to `'product=paper'`
2. My producer application sends another message the same way also with `'product=paper'`.
3. I can see both messages in the queue when I browse that message's headers in the Artemis UI. `_AMQ_GROUP_ID` has a value of `'product=paper'` in both.  `JMSXGroupID` is absent.
4. When I debug my listener application which uses Spring JMS with a concurrency of 15-15 (15 min 15 max) I can see both messages come through logged under different listener containers.  When I look at the map of headers for each, `_AMQ_GROUP_ID` is absent and `JMSXGroupID` has a value of null instead of `'product=paper'`.

Why isn't message grouping with group id working?  Does it have to do with the fact that Artemis didn't translate `_AMQ_GROUP_ID` back to `JMSXGroupID`?  Or is Spring JMS not registering its multiple consumer threads as different consumers for the broker to see multiple consumers?

Edit:
I was able to get message grouping to work in my application by commenting out lines having to do with using transacted sessions from my container factory bean method.  It seems to have to do with using transacted sessions.

Edit2:

Here's a self contained application running against a local standalone Artemis broker (version 2.10.1) and using Spring Boot 2.2.0:

GroupidApplication (spring boot application and beans):

```
package com.reproduce.groupid;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Session;

import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.TransportConfiguration;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.jms.ActiveMQJMSClient;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.jms.JMSFactoryType;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageType;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class GroupidApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(GroupidApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Autowired MessageConverter messageConverter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOG.info("STARTING THE APPLICATION");
        SpringApplication.run(GroupidApplication.class, args);

        LOG.info("APPLICATION FINISHED");
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws JMSException {
        LOG.info("EXECUTING : command line runner");

        jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);

        createAndSendTextMessage("Message1");
        createAndSendTextMessage("Message2");
        createAndSendTextMessage("Message3");
        createAndSendTextMessage("Message4");
        createAndSendTextMessage("Message5");
        createAndSendTextMessage("Message6");
    }

    private void createAndSendTextMessage(String messageBody) {
        jmsTemplate.send("local-queue", session -> {
            Message message = session.createTextMessage(messageBody);

            message.setStringProperty("JMSXGroupID", "product=paper");

            return message;
        });
    }


    // BEANS
    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> containerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer, JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();

        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
        factory.setSubscriptionShared(true);
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
        factory.setSessionTransacted(Boolean.TRUE);
        factory.setTransactionManager(jmsTransactionManager);

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager = new JmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory);

        // Lazily retrieve existing JMS Connection from given ConnectionFactory
        jmsTransactionManager.setLazyResourceRetrieval(true);

        return jmsTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws JMSException {
        // Create ConnectionFactory which enables failover between primary and backup brokers
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMqConnectionFactory = ActiveMQJMSClient.createConnectionFactoryWithHA(
                JMSFactoryType.CF, transportConfigurations());

        activeMqConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL("tcp://localhost:61616?jms.redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveries=1");
        activeMqConnectionFactory.setUser("admin");
        activeMqConnectionFactory.setPassword("admin");
        activeMqConnectionFactory.setInitialConnectAttempts(1);
        activeMqConnectionFactory.setReconnectAttempts(5);
        activeMqConnectionFactory.setConsumerWindowSize(0);
        activeMqConnectionFactory.setBlockOnAcknowledge(true);
        activeMqConnectionFactory.setCacheDestinations(true);
        activeMqConnectionFactory.setRetryInterval(1000);

        return activeMqConnectionFactory;
    }

    private static TransportConfiguration[] transportConfigurations() {
        String connectorFactoryFqcn = NettyConnectorFactory.class.getName();
        Map<String, Object> primaryTransportParameters = new HashMap<>(2);

        primaryTransportParameters.put("host", "localhost");
        primaryTransportParameters.put("port", "61616");

        TransportConfiguration primaryTransportConfiguration = new TransportConfiguration(connectorFactoryFqcn,
                primaryTransportParameters);

        return new TransportConfiguration[] { primaryTransportConfiguration,
                new TransportConfiguration(connectorFactoryFqcn) };
    }
}
```

CustomSpringJmsListener:

```
package com.reproduce.groupid;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomSpringJmsListener {

    protected final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @JmsListener(destination = "local-queue", subscription = "groupid-example", containerFactory = "containerFactory", concurrency = "15-15")
    public void receive(TextMessage message) throws JMSException {
        LOG.info("Received message: " + message);
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.reproduce</groupId>
    <artifactId>groupid</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>groupid</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

You can see that even though all of these messages have the same group id, they get logged by different listener container threads.  If you comment out the transaction manager from the bean definition it starts working again.

Comment: What happens if you remove Spring JMS from the use-case and just use a normal JMS `MessageConsumer`? Eliminating Spring JMS will indicate whether the issue is with Spring JMS or with Artemis itself.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58399905/amq-group-id-present-in-message-but-jmsxgroupid-null-in-jmslistener/58400738#58400738). It is a bug in the artemis client (2.6.4); it works with 2.10.1.

Comment: @GaryRussell I think this is a separate issue.   In a the same example from that question you linked group id was actually working it just wasn't coming through in the headers.

Comment: @JustinBertram I was able to get it working in a simple example.  In my actual application I narrowed it down to using `Session.TRANSACTED`.  Editing my question to show the relevant configurations.

Comment: What happens if you use a transacted session in a non-Spring, JMS-only client?

Comment: @JustinBertram I'm not sure how to use the standard jms api to have multiple concurrent consumers listenening on the same topic with the same listener.

Comment: You could write a simple Java app with a `main()` method which subscribes to the topic and just run that application multiple times.

Comment: Group id is respected when using the low level jms api.  `consumer.receive()` times out if another consumer already processed a message with the same groupid until that consumer takes care of that message. I'm using `connection.createSession(Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED)` and `session.commit()`

Comment: @GaryRussell Any thoughts on this?  Should I create a separate question specifically for spring jms and artemis with transacted sessions?

Comment: Are you still using the old artemis client that doesn't map the incoming property correctly? If you can post a small application that reproduces the issue someplace, I can take a look.

Comment: No, using Spring 2.2.0 and Artemis broker version 2.10.1.  I think this is a different issue than the mapping of headers.  Group ID isn't being honored for message grouping when a transaction manager is involved.  Maybe I'm configuring transacted sessions incorrectly?

Comment: You can see that even though all of these messages have the same group id, they get logged by different listener container threads.  If you comment out the transaction manager from the bean definition it starts working again.

Comment: @GaryRussell Forgot to mention in my comments that I edited the question to include a self-contained example.  Just comment out the line where the transaction manager is set to see message grouping bring working in the console logs.

Comment: Good thing you added this comment; for some reason I didn't get notified of yesterday's comments and they are not in my reponses history. I'll take a look and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about consumer caching. By default, when using an external TXM, caching is disabled so each message is received on a new consumer.

For this app, you really don't need a transaction manager, `sessionTransacted` is enough - the container will use local transactions.

If you must use an external transaction manager for some reason, consider changing the cache level.

```
factory.setCacheLevel(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.CACHE_CONSUMER);
```

See the DMLC javadocs...

```
/**
 * Specify the level of caching that this listener container is allowed to apply.
 * <p>Default is {@link #CACHE_NONE} if an external transaction manager has been specified
 * (to reobtain all resources freshly within the scope of the external transaction),
 * and {@link #CACHE_CONSUMER} otherwise (operating with local JMS resources).
 * <p>Some Java EE servers only register their JMS resources with an ongoing XA
 * transaction in case of a freshly obtained JMS {@code Connection} and {@code Session},
 * which is why this listener container by default does not cache any of those.
 * However, depending on the rules of your server with respect to the caching
 * of transactional resources, consider switching this setting to at least
 * {@link #CACHE_CONNECTION} or {@link #CACHE_SESSION} even in conjunction with an
 * external transaction manager.
 * @see #CACHE_NONE
 * @see #CACHE_CONNECTION
 * @see #CACHE_SESSION
 * @see #CACHE_CONSUMER
 * @see #setCacheLevelName
 * @see #setTransactionManager
 */
public void setCacheLevel(int cacheLevel) {
```

Comment: That did it!  Thank you.  Is there any good documentation to help me understand transaction management and caching with spring jms that you would recommend?  These configurations still feel like magic to me.

Comment: I am not aware of anything outside of the javadocs and Spring Framework reference JMS and transactions chapters. Generally, you only need to inject a transaction manager if you want to synchronize transactions (e.g. DB and JMS) or if you are running in a managed container (JEE). The latter is why they decided on those defaults (JEE was commonly used when spring-jms was first created).